# svg image inside span tag in mobi file not display numbers

Tags: svg, kindle-fire

when put svg image inside span tag like

```
<span>
<svg:svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svgmath="http://www.grigoriev.ru/svgmath" height="15.405117pt" width="14.613340pt" viewBox="0 -11.686934 14.613340 15.405117"><svg:metadata><svgmath:metrics top="15.4051171875" axis="7.70255859375" baseline="3.71818359375" bottom="0.0" /></svg:metadata><svg:g transform="translate(0.000000, -3.984375)"><svg:g transform="translate(5.066426, -1.599609)"><svg:text font-size="8.520000" text-anchor="middle" y="0.000000" x="2.240244" font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black">1</svg:text></svg:g><svg:g transform="translate(0.585938, 7.702559)"><svg:text font-size="8.520000" text-anchor="middle" y="0.000000" x="6.720732" font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black">100</svg:text></svg:g><svg:line stroke-width="0.585938" x1="0.000000" x2="14.613340" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-dasharray="none" y1="0.000000" y2="0.000000" fill="none" /></svg:g></svg:svg>
</span>
```

and generate kindle mobi file the fraction numbers does not appear but when use div instead it shown correctly.
How can I display correct svg inside span????

Comment: You could try giving the span a style of display:block

Comment: first I want span to be inline, second I tried this and also fraction numbers not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution by putting the svg inside object tag that refer to the svg file